# How to prove that $\partial(\partial{E})\subseteq\partial{E}$?

Tags: general-topology

I know that $\partial(A\cap{B})\subseteq{[\overline{A}\cap\partial{B}]\cup[\partial{A}\cap\overline{B}]}$, that $\partial{E}=\partial(X\setminus{E})$, that $\partial{E}=\overline{E}\cap{\overline{X\setminus{E}}}$ and that $\overline{\overline{E}}=\overline{E} $ and then it result that $x\in\partial{\overline{E}}\Rightarrow\forall{V_x}\in\mathcal{V(x)}:V_x\cap{E}\neq\varnothing\Rightarrow{x}\in{\overline{\overline{E}}}=\overline{E}\Rightarrow\partial\overline{E}\subseteq\overline{E}$: so in the first inclusion let us assume $A=\overline{E}$ and $B=\overline{X\setminus{E}}$, it result $\partial(\partial{E})=\partial(\overline{E}\cap{\overline{X\setminus{E}}})\subseteq(\overline{\overline{E}}\cap\partial(\overline{X\setminus{E}}))\cup(\partial\overline{E}\cap\overline{\overline{X\setminus{E}}})=(\overline{E}\cap\partial(\overline{X\setminus{E}}))\cup(\partial\overline{E}\cap\overline{X\setminus{E}})\subseteq(\overline{E}\cap\overline{X\setminus{E}})\cup(\overline{E}\cap\overline{X\setminus{E}})=(\overline{E}\cap\overline{X\setminus{E}})=\partial{E}$

Is it my reasoning correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\partial G=\overline G\cap \overline {X\setminus G}$ is the intersection of 2 closed sets, and is a subset of $\overline G.$

So $ \partial E=   \overline {\partial E}$ and  $\overline F\supset \partial F.$

With $F=\partial E$ we have $\partial E= \overline {\partial E}=\overline F\supset \partial F=\partial\partial E.$

Comment: If  $E$ is dense and co-dense, that is if $\overline E=X=\overline {X\setminus E},$ then $\partial E=X$ and  $\partial  \partial E=\emptyset.$ E.g. if $X=\Bbb R$ with the usual topology, and $E=\Bbb Q.$

Answer (score 1):

From the definition that $x \in \partial B$ iff every open neighbourhood of $x$ intersects both $B$ and $B^\complement$:

Suppose $x \in \partial(\partial E)$. Let $O$ be an open neighbourhood of $x$. Then in particular, $O \cap \partial E \neq \emptyset$, so pick $y \in O \cap \partial E$. Then $O$, also being an open neighbourhood of $y \in \partial E$, intersects $E$ and $E^\complement$. As $O$ was an arbitrary open neighbourhood of $x$ we have shown $x \in \partial E$ and the inclusion has been shown.

Answer (score 0):

Every closed set contains its boundary. Since the boundary of any set is the intersection of two closed sets, it is closed. Therefore the boundary of $\partial{E}$ is contained within $\partial{E}$